# Make Bot Discord Py react

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my code:
and it seemes that it doesn't work

```
emojis = [
    'regional_indicator_b',
    'regional_indicator_e', ]

    latency = (client.latency * 1000).__round__()
    await ctx.send(f"Ping: {latency} ms")
    for emoji in emojis:
        await ctx.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Comment: Were there any errors given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using `regional_indicator_b` would give an error of `PException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji`, so instead you could use unicode. You can find more of these [with this link here.](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F1E6)
- Assuming you were trying to add a reaction to the message the bot sent, it would give an error of `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'`. You would have to define the message the bot sent as seen below, where the bot's message would be known as `msg`, and it would then react to `msg`.

```py
@client.command()
async def so(ctx):
    emojis = [
    '\U0001F1E6',#regional_indicator_A
    '\U0001F1FF']#regional_indicator_Z

    latency = (client.latency * 1000).__round__()
    msg = await ctx.send(f"Ping: {latency} ms")#define the message the bot sends so it reacts to this message
    for emoji in emojis:
        await msg.add_reaction(emoji)#react
```

Comment: How do you get the unicode number ? Is that encoding 32 bit ?

Comment: I did this list [emojis = 
    '\U00000042',
    '\U00000045',
    '\U0000006E',
    '\U0000007A',
    '\U0000006F',
    '\U0000006E',
    '\U0001F1FF'
]

Comment: You're going to want to use UTF-32 encoding, so if we used alphabets as an example: `emojis = ['\U0001F1E6', '\U0001F1E7', '\U0001F1E8', '\U0001F1E9']` etcetera.

Comment: From where do you get these? You found the letter B as "'\U0001F1E7'" but I found it as "\U00000042"

Comment: If you followed the link I had posted in my answer (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F1E6), you'll be lead to the letter A. Towards the bottom you'll find something that says `UTF-32 Encoding: 0x0001F1E6`. This would be written as `\U0001F1E6`. Using the arrows on the right side, you'll be able to find the other letters you need.